# Inserting row in database, error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have been trying to add a row in my database but i keep on recieving the same error no matter what I do. The error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING .
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysql5.000webhost.com","********","******","*******");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
//Connecting to the Database works
INSERT INTO test (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES (\'11\', \'11\', \'11\', \'11\');
mysqli_close($con);
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Um if you read the manual or any tutorial or had a decent PHP editor you'd spot this by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute a query - [`mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

```
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO test (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES ('11', '11', '11', '11')");
```

Answer (score 2):

remove the `\` in the statement,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES ('11', '11', '11', '11')";
```

but if the columns are integer,

```
$query = "INSERT INTO test (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES (11, 11, 11, 11)";
```

Comment: This is correct, but this does not address that the OP is also missing `mysqli_query()`/`$sql->query()` to actually execute the `INSERT`.

Comment: @Sean I'm not showing here the execution but only the syntax to be executed. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I notice your sql statement is written as if it was php code. SQL is not parsed directly by php interpreter. you need to first put the sql into a variable then execute that statement. also, you are escaping the single quotes, not good

```
     $sql="INSERT INTO test (`1`, `2`, `3`, `4`) VALUES ('11', '11', '11', '11')";
    $result = $db->query($sql);

    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
       $retval[]= $data;
    }
```

assuming $db is a valid connection

Comment: why is your `$sql` after your `$result = $this->db->query($sql);`? Also, why are showing to do `$result->fetch_assoc()` on an `INSERT`?

Comment: lol my mistake I did a test within a class, I will edit my post

Comment: When I ran your script it gave me the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in"